recursive query postgresql not running recursively
The below query runs and works without errors. However, it is not running recursively. Can someone point me in the right direction on why this might be?
with recursive parentlots as(
    with
        child_lot as (
            select * from materiallot where id = 'H999230306001'
        )
    select 
    (select id from child_lot limit 1) as child_lot_id, 
    (select quantity from child_lot limit 1) as child_lot_quantity,
    ml.id as parent_lot_id
    from materiallot ml
    join materiallot_ap ap on ap.uid = ml.uid
    join materiallotlink l on ml.uid = l.parentmateriallotuid
    where l.childmateriallotuid = (select uid from child_lot limit 1)
    
    union
    
    select 
    (select id from child_lot limit 1) as child_lot_id, 
    (select quantity from child_lot limit 1) as child_lot_quantity,
    ml.id as parent_lot_id
    from materiallot ml
    inner join parentlots pl on child_lot_id = parent_lot_id
)
select * from parentlots
order by parent_lot_id

EDIT* Adding data output. The parents should become the children if they have children and so on. This is the part that is not working.


I haven't used recursive cte in a long time, but it looks rather odd to have a CTE within the Recursive CTE. May be totally fine but just never how I've used it.

I was thinking this might be the issue as well. I need to think about how I can change that to test it.

Try to specify table aliases in on child_lot_id = parent_lot_id

@Serg I am unsure what you mean. These come from the above select ... as ... Can you expand on this?

Looks like you want child_lot_id  from one table and parent_lot_id from the other one. Specify which one is which explicitly. My guess is you are currently comparing columns of the same table which is never true

@Serg Those are actually columns from the same table but with different conditions. child_lot_id is supposed to start here "where id = 'H999230306001'". parent_lot_id comes from here where l.childmateriallotuid = (select uid from child_lot limit 1). These are from the same table but with differen where clauses. But I agree that this is probably the issue. I am unsure how to resolve it though.

How about putting the sample data as text not images, and show your expected results.

Rewrite the query without the additional CTE and see what happens.

@LaurenzAlbe I am unsure how to rewrite this with the the other CTE since it used it multiple times. Can you help get me started?

That's hard, because the query is so confusing that I have no idea what it is trying to do.
